# Wordpress global vars no works in function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 global vars defined inside funtions.php , the value of this vars to take from include file :

```
global $ruta_path;
global $ruta_db;
```

I want send the value of this global values to function in comments but no get works

Inside comments.php i have this function - no put all content here:

```
<?php 

global $ruta_path;
global $ruta_db;


function p_comment( $comment, $args, $depth )
{

global $ruta_path;
global $ruta_db;

/// to take value of global vars global $ruta_path; global $ruta_db;

} 

?>
```

Also under of this i can see the structure of divs for comments and inside i have this :

```
<?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'p_comment' ) ); ?>
```

The case i´m turn crazy with this because i try all and no send the values of global vars i need this for work but no get i try with $GLOBALS and continue no working , how i can use this global vars and send to function and when callback call function for these comments because i try all and no get the function and call back take the values

Thank´s !!!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better set to create your globals and function definition within the `functions.php` file, for more info on the [purpose of this file refer to the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained). If you are defining the global vars and function only within the comments.php you risk issue with the callback not firing against a registered function within the global space.